# Recursion question for CS

Tags: functions

[image]

Is this correct if not where have i gone wrong?

$$f(x)= 20+f(x+1)$$

Comment: Try computing f(0) using your formula and see what happens.

Comment: Write out $f(x+1)$ and $f(x)$. Subtract. What will you get?

Comment: Mine doesn't make sense -.-

Answer (score 2):

It is not correct. One thing you need is a starting point (e.g., $f(0) = 20$). This is required if you want to make a recursive function. Additionally, I believe the function you're looking for is the following:

$f(0) = 20, f(x) = f(x-1) + 20 + x $

The rate of change in this function is $20 + x$, so if you were to add it to the last term, you would get the following term. It would help for me to know how you derived your formula in order to tell you where you went wrong.

Comment: hey mtiano, what's wrong with it ?

Comment: I just posted the right equation. Try a few points, and you'll see what he means. Sorry for the confusion, I didn't look hard enough at your function.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Also for http://vvcap.net/db/_ztpRzOUTODzryySWe-P.htp would the following question would the definition subfive(X) = 250+subfive(x-1)+(-5) be correct?

Comment: Please review my edited post and see if you agree with it mtiano.

Comment: Are you referring to me or mtiano ? I can't really say whether i agree with it because i was unsure ;p

Comment: I was referring to mtiano. PS: your subfive function is not correct. Remember: you are staring with 250 and the difference each time is -5. How would you make this recursive? What is the first term?